# Exclude few key value from json which are already mapped in some were

Tags: mule, dataweave

I need to remove some fields from the output while mapping a set of attributes.

Input:

```
[
    {
        "eventType": "xxx",
        "entityId": "xxxxxx",
        "userName": "xxxxx",
        "dateTime": "2010-11-11T07:00:00Z",
        "status": "SHIPPED",
        "additionalData": {
            "quoteId": "xxxxx",
            "clientReferenceId": "Srites004",
            "modifiedDt": "2010-11-11T07:00:00Z",
            "packageId": "AIM_PACKAGE",
            "sbsOrderId": "TEST-TS-201809-79486",
            "orderReferenceId": "xxxxxx",
            "shipDate_1": "2010-11-11T07:00:00Z",
            "shipDate_2": "2010-11-12T07:00:00Z",
            "shipDate_3": "2010-11-13T07:00:00Z",
            "shipMethod_1": "UPS Ground",
            "shipMethod_3": "UPS Ground3",
            "shipMethod_2": "UPS Ground2",
            "trackingNumber_3": "333",
            "trackingNumber_1": "2222",
            "trackingNumber_2": "221"
        }
    }
]
```

Output:

```
{
    "attribute_name": {
        "sbsOrderId": "xxx",
        "packageId": "xxxx"
    }
}
```

These fields should not be mapped in output:

["shipDate","shipMethod","trackingNumber","quoteId","quote-proof-composition-pageCount","quote-proof-composition-asset","preflightErrorReport","modifiedDt","clientReferenceId","schoolIds","orderReferenceId"]

My current dataweave:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
---
attribute_name:
            (pl.additionalData mapObject {
(($$) :[$]) when  not ( ($$ contains "shipDate") or ($$ contains "shipMethod") or ($$ contains "trackingNumber") or ($$ contains "quoteId")  or ($$ contains "quote-proof-composition-pageCount") or ($$ contains  "quote-proof-composition-asset") or ($$ contains  "preflightErrorReport") or ($$ contains "modifiedDt") or ($$ contains  "clientReferenceId") or ($$ contains "schoolIds") or ($$ contains "orderReferenceId"))})
    ]]}
```

It's working fine, but I need to make the dw more simple.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to clean things up, I think a good way to do this is to put the keys you don't want into an array, and check that the key in the object you're mapping is in that array. This makes it very easy to add/subtract fields as requirements change.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json

%var unwantedKeys = [
  "shipDate",
  "shipMethod",
  "trackingNumber",
  "quoteId",
  "quote-proof-composition-pageCount",
  "quote-proof-composition-asset",
  "preflightErrorReport",
  "modifiedDt",
  "clientReferenceId",
  "schoolIds",
  "orderReferenceId"
]

%function filterUnwantedKeys(value, key)
  {(key): value}
    unless (unwantedKeys contains (key as :string))
    otherwise {}
---
{
  attribute_name: 
    payload.additionalData mapObject filterUnwantedKeys($, $$)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing all of the ones you don't want, how about keeping the ones you do want?

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
attribute_name: payload.additionalData mapObject {
    sbsOrderId: $.sbsOrderId,
    packageId: $.packageId
}
```

This produced the desired output:

```
{
  "attribute_name": {
    "sbsOrderId": "TEST-TS-201809-79486",
    "packageId": "AIM_PACKAGE"
  }
}
```

After clarification, this is the only thing that comes to mind, and it's not much prettier:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
attribute_name: payload.additionalData mapObject (
    $
    -- $["quoteId"]
    -- $["clientReferenceId"]
    -- $["modifiedDt"]
    -- $["orderReferenceId"]
    -- $["shipDate_1"]
    -- $["shipDate_2"]
    -- $["shipDate_3"]
    -- $["shipMethod_1"]
    -- $["shipMethod_2"]
    -- $["shipMethod_3"]
    -- $["trackingNumber_1"]
    -- $["trackingNumber_2"]
    -- $["trackingNumber_3"]
)
```

Comment: actually input comes different (means new field will come) thats why

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. :)

Comment: its will be lengthy